# Strings- taking out a letter at the start of each string in a list

Tags: python, string, list, loops, call

I am new to coding and am doing a computer science class. I have enjoyed it so far. the following Question has stumped me:

1. An acronym is a string of capital letters formed by taking the first letters from a phrase. For example, SADD is an acronym for “students against drunk driving”. Note that the acronym should be composed of all capital letters even if the original words are not. Write a program that has the user input a phrase and then prints the corresponding acronym.
   These questions will help you put together the final program:
2. What type of data will the input be? What type of data will the output be?
3. Get the phrase from the user.
4. Convert to upper case.
5. Divide the phrase into words
6. Initialize a new empty list, letters.
7. Get the first letter of each word
8. Append the first letter to the list letters.
9. Join the letters together, with no space between them
10. Print the acronym.

I have done steps 1 through 4 confidently. 5 I am not to sure. 6 i dont know how i get the first letter of each word.

Here is my code:

```
use_input = input("Please write a phrase and i will turn it into an acronym")

use_input_uppercase = use_input.upper()

use_input_uppercase_split = use_input_uppercase.split()

letters = list(use_input_uppercase_split)

for use_input_uppercase_split in letters:
```

I am not sure what to do to to call the first letter of each word.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is three lines:

```
data = input('Enter a phrase: ') # get user input
data = [i[0] for i in data.upper().split(' ')] 

# 1. String converted to uppercase.
# 2. String split at spaces.
# 3. First letters are taken.

print ''.join(data) # back to string
```

Here's an example execution:

```
>>> 
Enter a phrase: you only live once
YOLO
>>>
```

Comment: It's not generally encouraged to just provide full code for what are obviously homework questions - it's far more effective to help guide and point the OP towards the right answer.

Comment: I explained in comments. Is it not sufficient?

Comment: I know, but you also provided the entire code. Now all the user has to do is copy/paste, get full marks on his assignment and not understand anything.

Comment: Should I expound on the explanation?